# How to reset after MCI Error #10: cannot load driver

Tags: mci

I am using MCI in a C++ program to play multiple short MP3 files.  Everything goes fine for several hours and hundreds of MP3 files played successfully.  Then suddenly, I get MCI Error #10: cannot load driver.  After this, I get the same error every time I open a new MP3 file.  To get things working again, I have to stop and restart my program, after which everything goes fine again for an hour or two.

I could live with this glitch, if only I knew how to reset things after the error occurred, without having to restart my program.

Note: I don't have a memory leak, memory usage is stable over the hours of running.

I have found this: [SetupDiRestartDevices function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Does anyone have exeperience using this with an audio device?  Do you think it might work from my program WITHOUT restarting the computer.